# *ngFor and [(ngModel)] together in Angular2 and Ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2

How can I use `*ngFor` and `[(ngModel)]` together to dynamically refresh data in list?
Simple code for example:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let task of tasks">
  {{task.title}}
</ion-item>
```

And let's say I change the title of some task.

Comment: question is not clear, actually what you want to do?

Comment: sorry if my question wasn't clear, I just want a simple list that will refresh its data if some changes of the data occurs somewhere

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there, just iterate the tasks and then you can use `[(ngModel)]` for each task, for example in an input field, since you mentioned to change `title` of some task. So your code would look like so:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let task of tasks">
  <ion-input [(ngModel)]="task.title"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```